# KBXXXXX does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer

Tags: windows-update, visual-studio-2010

I have uninstalled VS 2010 and many other apps that I don't use anymore, and reinstalled it after. I have also reinstalled VS 2010 SP1.

I'm now down to 3 updates, of which I am getting the error:

"KB2522890 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer."

I have already disabled my antivirus and Windows Defender.

It also happens to the other updates:

VS10SP1-KB2529927-v2-x86

VS10SP1-KB2548139-x86

VS10SP1-KB2549864-x86

It is possible that Microsoft Update is right that they do not apply, as I only installed VS 2010 C# and Web development. Why is it recommending that I install them then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Windows Update isn't as accurate as the Installer itself.
The installer would be the definitive authority here.

The patches just look like hotfixes. So unless you these problems, I wouldn't bother.

[VS10SP1-KB2529927-v2-x86](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=36587)

> Title KB2529927
>   Release Date  4/29/2011
>   Hotfix Description    Migrating setup project
>   from VS2008 to VS2010SP1 changes component GUIDs, which causes
>   upgrades to fail.

[VS10SP1-KB2548139-x86](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=36587)

> Title KB2548139
>   Release Date  6/9/2011
>   Description   VS GDR for
>   Web Platform Tools: VS2010SP1 crash in 
>   FPEDITAX.DLL!LaidView::FindProperties()

[VS10SP1-KB2549864-x86](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=37409)

> Title KB2549864
>   Release Date  7/19/2011
>   1) Report is not 508 compliant, when
>   viewed through ReportViewer control from a web application, for the
>   new ReportViewer control 2010 SP1, for remote processing
>
> 2) ReportViewer Drillthrough Broken after VS2010 SP1

Answer (score 0):

Those are "hotfixes", rather than "updates".  If you're not experiencing the specific problems they address, you shouldn't be installing them as they are not considered fully stable by MS.

Are these being offered to you by Windows Update?  Hotfixes usually aren't, so that's weird. :)  If they are, perhaps try flushing your Windows Update cache to get WU to re-detect which updates you need.

Some hotfixes patch the same files as other hotfixes, causing other hotfixes to not apply anymore as their specific fixes were included in the one installed first.

You can check the associated KB articles and they will tell you which files will be patched to which versions so you can go compare them to what you have currently (to manually determine if the hotfix needs to be applied).